# Admin user login when starting with DrupalVM?

Tags: drupal

Running Drupal 7 on DrupalVM. Had a successful installation, but when I visited my Drupal site, it requires a login and password. I couldn't find in the docs where the root admin login credentials are. Usually Drupal allows you to set this up, but not the case with DrupalVM (unless its in a config file and I overlooked it). Are there root login credentials or do you have to create an admin user (through your db) when first getting started with DrupalVM? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Username and password: admin:admin https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm#3---configure-your-host-machine-to-access-the-vm

Comment: Oh, wow! Thanks - not sure how I missed that (must've read over it a half dozen times). Appreciate it.